# Display Less than Total Minutes - String not recognized as DateTime

Tags: asp.net, datetime

Hi I am trying to display "Less than a Minute ago", "Minutes Ago" for my DateTime.

However I am getting the error String Not Recognized as DateTime when I ParseExact it.

Please check out my code:

```
  Dim display As String = Nothing
        Dim MyString As String
        MyString = "2015-02-18 10:34:00 PM"
        Dim MyDateTime As DateTime
        MyDateTime = New DateTime
        MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", Nothing)

    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim counter As Integer = Nothing

    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        counter = counter + 1

        Dim t As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - MyDateTime

        If t.TotalSeconds < 60 Then
            display = "Less than a minute ago"
        ElseIf t.TotalMinutes < 60 Then
            display = t.Minutes.ToString() + " minutes ago"
        End If

        sb.AppendFormat("<a href=""#"" class=""list-group-item"">" &
        "<span class=""badge"">" & display & "</span>" &
        "<i class=""fa fa-fw fa-comment""></i> " & dt.Rows(i).Item("Message") & "</a>")
        If counter = 9 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Literal1.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

The Display String is suppose to output the Less Than a Minute ago and Minutes ago feature.

But the error for

String not recognized as DateTime:

Appears on the line:

> MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",
>   Nothing)

Comment: The message means that the string you are trying to parse isn't in the expected format. Your format string expects Hours and minutes while the time string has seconds. Try to remove them :-)

Comment: If you want a library to automatically do this for you, check out [Humanizer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekHumanizerMakesNETDataTypesMoreHuman.aspx).

Comment: Changed it to    MyString = "2015-02-18 10:34 PM" still getting error

Comment: That's strange. When the format is changed to `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt"` which should be the correct thing to do, it works with `AM`, but it still fails with `PM`. I'm lost on this one

Comment: I think I fixed it by adding :SS and switching the time.